# Ping in Azure mobile service

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I have channels for push notification. Can I use this adresses for ping user's device? I want to know the count of online users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The push notification channels could give you a rather rough count of devices that are reachable at a given instant, but it would potentially double-count the same user on multiple devices and it would be the number that receive the notification (roughly), not the number that are in your app at that time.

Keep in mind too that users could turn off notifications, and if you're surfacing toasts or tiles without perceptible value to the user, they're likely to get rather annoyed and potentially uninstall your app.

Analytics providers like Flurry and Localytics might be an option to provide finer granularity and better accuracy on user behavior.  Or simply add some code into your own app to provide the level of tracking required; notifications seems like a rather backdoor means to this end.